# How to write Bidirectional text in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I want to write text which contain words from RTL and LTR languages. How I can achieve that?

Now, I can write the words just right but in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by adding "Arabic" language in your keyboard preference which you can switch as per your requirement.

[For Linux (Ubuntu user)](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17508/add-keyboard-input-language-to-ubuntu/)

[For Windows User](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-keyboard-input-language)

Comment: I can right Arabic just fine. But the direction to text is from left-to-right, which make the text display the words in wrong order.

Comment: Once you will change the language of your keyboard, by default text would appear right to left on typing from a keyword.